# The underlying connection was closed. An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: c#, .net, api, httpwebrequest

I am trying to connect to an API. I will preface this and say this is a project we were working on months ago, and it was working, at least in the sense i could reach out and get the data from the API fine. We put the project on hold for a couple months, come back to it, and now the connection to this one API no longer works. In the project we are connecting to 2 API's and the second API connections work fine still. I have attempted to recreate the request using the same headers in Postman and it works fine. I have had this issue before, and adding the line:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Solved it for me in the past, but i have that code in the method and it still fails now.

**Below is the full method:**

```
var encodedData = System.Convert.ToBase64String(
                                    System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
                                    .GetBytes("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:")
                                ); 

string headerString = "Basic " + encodedData;

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx);

httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, headerString);
httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;    

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
//ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768;   
//ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

Console.WriteLine("Protocol: " + ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol);

//ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
//                           SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
//                           SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();   

    writelog("Result: " + result);
}
```

Not sure if this helps, but when i try to analyze the traffic in Fiddler, i can see the request coming out of Postman fine, but when i run the above code i never get any traffic leaving my network. Just alot of traffic from localhost to /vshub/XXXXXXXXXXX. I have also tried other permutations of the `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` as you can see from the commented out code, but none have worked.

I am at wits end trying to solve this. 
Any help would be appreciated! 
Oh, i am on `runtime 4.0` and `framework 4.6`.

UPDATE: Ran the code on alternate machines using the same runtime and framework and it works fine. It seems more and more likely to be a Firewall issue on my local machine.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: maybe your app is blocked by firewall?

Comment: You know, i thought that could be it at one point, and i looked at the list of applications allowed and the only entry for visual studio was allowed. Is there something else in that list i should be looking for that you know of? I also thought windows update may have broken it as well. I had a similar issue about a year ago where after a windows update api calls failed. Uninstalling the update fixed it. Too many updates have been installed over the last few months to hunt and delete thought

Comment: Http uses TCP as the transport layer.  Fiddler combines the TCP messages into HTTP automatically.  If you are not seeing the HTTP is means you didn't complete the TCP connection.  So I would try using the computer name instead of the IP address.  If DCHP is enabled then the IP address will change periodically.

Comment: When i look at the traffic in Fiddler, i do see that the protocol for the VS stuff is HTTP, so that looks ok. It just never seems to actually send data to the API address as the host. It all stays localhost, as opposed to running the request in Postman. When i do watch the traffic in Fiddler when running it in Postman, i see a http request going out to the API address.

Comment: @user519670 Have you tried removing all the ServicePointManager modification calls, and let the code run as .net sees best.  You are forcing TLS 1.2 in your current version I see, so if your server doesn't support it you will get these results.  You should really try avoiding these statements if possible and let .Net determine the appropriate version of SSL/TLS to authenticate with.

Comment: I have, and got the same result. With outputting the protocol it selects before sending the request, i do see that when i take all calls out to that code, it uses both SSL3 and Tls.

Comment: You need to set the TLS protocol before this line: var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx); just FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. I tried running the code on other machines with a fresh install of Visual Studio. It worked fine on all other machines. I reinstalled VS on my local machine and the code worked. Not sure what changed to my VS over the last month or two but something clearly got corrupted.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually an issue related to TLS protocol.
Using this before calling service should solve the issue,

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```